# Bounded Anomaly Score between 0 and 1

Tags: outliers, normalization, standardization, anomaly-detection, z-score

I am using a KNN anomaly detection approach, where the distance to my nearest neighbor is an indication for an anomaly.

I am wondering how I can normalize the score between 0 and 1. I can use a test dataset without anomalies to get the normal data distribution. When I calculate the z-score it's not bounded between 0 and 1. The sigmoid function applied on the z-score returns too high values.

Is there some statistical approach based on the data distribution that returns a probability value that my distance value (or z-score) is an outlier?

Comment: why not score / max(score) ? That'll be in 0-1 (a distance is always positive)

Comment: because I don't know before what is my max value as there can always be a new anomaly which has a higher value.

Comment: How do you know that the scores arising from the sigmoid function are too high?

Comment: "Is there some statistical approach based on the data distribution that returns a probability value that my distance value (or z-score) is an outlier?" -- how do you define "outlier"?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the assumption that the z-scores are normally distributed, 
it is easy to convert the score to the probability of encountering a 
point  that far away or farther  `p(x >= abs(z))`.  For example,  in R
you could write:  `Score = 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))`

Comment: Even if the data are Gaussian (which is often doubtful when one is tempted to remove outliers) the z-score do not follow a Gaussian distribution. I guess it would be closer to student distribution but this is not even the case.